# NiFi EvaluateJSONPath loop through array to get correct value

Tags: json, apache-nifi

here is an example of some JSON that I need to deal with:

```
    {  
        "name": "John Smith",
        "active": "yes",
        "cpair": [
            {
                "title": "ADDRESS",
                "charVal": "1234 Fulcrum lane"
            },
            {
                "title": "phone",
                "charVal": "555-7600"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So I'm using the evaluateJsonPath processor to add these values as attributes in my flowfile. thats easy for some. I can just set name equal to $.name and active to $.active. But lets say I need to give the attribute 'address' the value of  "1234 Fulcrum lane". How do I assign that attribute the proper charVal value that matches up with the correct title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [Jayway JsonPath documentation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath)

this should work:

```
$.cpair[?(@.title == 'ADDRESS')].charVal
```

Comment: That does it, but why is it returning ["1234 Fulcrum lane"] instead of  just 1234 Fulcrum lane?

Comment: Ah.  it returns an array because theoretically you could have several objects with `ADDRESS`. Try `[0]` at the end